# What does x % 2 ==0 mean?

Tags: python

I'm sure it's very basic and I should understand it, but I don't!

I'm given this to do:

Loop through and print out all even numbers from the numbers list in the same order they are received. Don't print any numbers that come after 237 in the sequence.

This is the program i have for these numbers.

```
numbers = [
    951, 402, 984, 651, 360, 69, 408, 319, 601, 485, 980, 507, 725, 547, 544, 
    615, 83, 165, 141, 501, 263, 617, 865, 575, 219, 390, 984, 592, 236, 105, 942, 941, 
    386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345, 
    399, 162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217, 
    815, 67, 104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717, 
    958, 609, 842, 451, 688, 753, 854, 685, 93, 857, 440, 380, 126, 721, 328, 753, 470, 
    743, 527
]

# your code goes here
for x in numbers:
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print x
    if x == 237:
        break
```

I get the right solution and everything right but I have no idea what the ==0 is there for.
The only reason I used it is because it was used in the other example during the lesson before the practice!

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm

Comment: what did you type into google

Comment: sorry I'm new to the business guys. People ask questions when they don't know so if I didn't know something how am I expected to know how to search for it.  I didn't know to type in operator... in fact I don't even know what that means.  Thanks for the ridicule.

Comment: @user2304000 This is a perfectly valid question, It does show research effort since you've given the code and explained the problem. The website only supports downvotes on questions that show no effort, so this should **not** be downvoted.

Answer (score 11):

`x % 2` gives the remainder after the integer division (when dealing with only integers such as in this case, otherwise a common type) of `x/2`. The `%` is called the modulo operator. Of course when the remainder is 0, the number is even.

[Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

> The `%` (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second. The numeric arguments are first converted to a common type. A zero right argument raises the `ZeroDivisionError` exception. The arguments may be floating point numbers, e.g., `3.14%0.7` equals `0.34` (since `3.14` equals `4*0.7 + 0.34`.) The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its second operand (or zero); the absolute value of the result is strictly smaller than the absolute value of the second operand [2].

Comment: +1. You might want to link to a reference explaining about modulo.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Good idea I included one

Comment: @user2304000 You can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) this answer if it helped best. I recommend reading the Python tutorial before asking further questions if you haven't already.

Answer (score 8):

`if x % 2 == 0` checks if a number is even.

`x % 2` is `1` when the number is odd, and `0` when it is even.

Comment: so the 0 essentially means true?

Comment: It means the number zero, nothing more. `x % 2` gives the remainder and we check if it is equal to zero.

Comment: `x == y` checks whether `x` equals `y`, hence `x == 0` checks whether `x` equals `0`.

Comment: why does % mean give remainder instead of /. and does that mean that there are no objects or is it a number?

Comment: @user2304000 Because `/` already gives you the result of the division, not the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

`== 0` means "equal to 0 (zero)". So `if foo == 0:` means "do the following if `foo` is equal to 0", thus `if x % 2 == 0:` means "do the following if `x % 2` is equal to 0".